# AES256 encryption objective c implementation

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c

i have two questions ,

Is it possible to integrate .jar file or Java source files into iphone application? We found JavaBridge, and Hello Bridge but we haven't found any  documentation how to configure? If possible please provide the way.

http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/AES_Java_Implementation this is java code for AES256,
i would like to write the same code for Objective C for my iphone application,
the frameworks of java is the issue , I am facing issue to find the corresponding frameworks for objective c , so is there a way to do this AES256 in Objective C.

I have tried xmlvm and java2objc for converting code but they are not giving corresponding frameworks when i have converted so , we were almost stuck up , how to implement this feature , any help is greatful.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CommonCrypto](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/CommonCrypto) as part of this handy library by [Jim Dovey](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain).

Comment: Hi @rckoenes , thanks for your help, and we have done some way like this code in this link http://pastie.org/426530 it is working fine to do encrypt and decryption in my iphone. We need this technology in doing some transaction based application in which there is server and client interaction should happen with encryption and decryption at client side and server side vice versa. It is working fine with small length strings but it is not working fine with large strings . What we observed is there is an issue with the "PADDING" with large strings .

Comment: The server side programme is Java based code for encryption or decrytpion logic , that is also AES128 algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant integrate java file into iPhone application. You have to use ObjectiveC or HTML,Java Script ([Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or other framework required)